# Can I store SQL Server sort order in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL within a stored procedure. Is there a way to remove the IF statement and pass the 'ASC'/'DESC' option as a variable?

I know I could do the query a number of different ways, or return a table and sort it externally etc. I would just like to know if I can avoid duplicating the CASE statement.

```
IF @sortOrder = 'Desc'
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #t_results
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'surname'           THEN surname END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'forename'          THEN forename END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'fullName'          THEN fullName END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'userId'            THEN userId END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'MobileNumber'      THEN MSISDN END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'DeviceStatus'      THEN DeviceStatus END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastPosition'      THEN LastPosition END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastAlert'         THEN LastAlert END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastCommunication' THEN LastCommunication END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastPreAlert'      THEN LastPreAlert END DESC 
    END
 ELSE
   BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #t_results
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'surname'           THEN surname END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'forename'          THEN forename END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'fullName'          THEN fullName END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'userId'            THEN userId END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'MobileNumber'      THEN MSISDN END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'DeviceStatus'      THEN DeviceStatus END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastPosition'      THEN LastPosition END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastAlert'         THEN LastAlert END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastCommunication' THEN LastCommunication END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastPreAlert'      THEN LastPreAlert END DESC 
    END
END
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass in @OrderBy int, where positive is ASC, negative is DESC, and the actual number is the column to sort by:

```
SELECT
    dt.yourColumn1
        ,dt.yourColumn2
        ,dt.yourColumn3
        ,CASE 
            WHEN @OrderBy>0 THEN dt.SortBy
            ELSE NULL
         END AS SortByAsc
        ,CASE 
            WHEN @OrderBy<0 THEN dt.SortBy
            ELSE NULL
         END AS SortByDesc
    FROM (SELECT
              yourColumn1
                  ,yourColumn2
                  ,yourColumn3
                  ,CASE
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 1 THEN surname
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 2 THEN forename
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 3 THEN fullName
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 4 THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),userId)
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 5 THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),MobileNumber
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 6 THEN DeviceStatus
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 7 THEN LastPosition
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 8 THEN CONVERT(varchar(23),LastAlert,121)
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) = 9 THEN CONVERT(varchar(23),LastCommunication,121)
                      WHEN ABS(@OrderBy) =10 THEN CONVERT(varchar(23),LastPreAlert,121)
                      ELSE NULL
                  END AS SortBy
              FROM YourTablesHere
              WHERE X=Y
         ) dt
    ORDER BY SortByAsc ASC, SortByDesc DESC
```

Just make sure you build a string that sort properly. Notice I used 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.mmm' for the dates and put the numbers into strings.  We usually put multiple columns together, so if you sort by surname, forename is used too, etc.  Watch out, if you do combine multiple columns you'll need to pad with zeros or spaces.

If you don't want the SortByAsc and SortByDesc columns to be in the result set, wrap the entire thing in a derived table.

Comment: They don't need to be in a derived table or in the result set. You can use expressions in your ORDER BY clause. I just submitted an example before I saw your response.
+1: Good point on the synchronizing of data types.

Comment: to eliminate duplicated CASE statement, it has to be a column

Answer (score 7):

You can do it without dynamic SQL...

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     My_Table
WHERE
     Whatever = @something
ORDER BY
     CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'ASC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN surname
                    WHEN 'forename' THEN forename
                    WHEN 'fullname' THEN fullname
                    ELSE surname
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END ASC,
     CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'DESC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN surname
                    WHEN 'forename' THEN forename
                    WHEN 'fullname' THEN fullname
                    ELSE surname
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END DESC
```

Comment: I revised my code, they are asking how to eliminate duplicating the CASE statement. I don't think that can be done in the ORDER BY. Also, I like my positive/negative parameter sort by better, it is easy in the application to multiple by -1 to toggle it & the value is the column number of the grid.

Comment: This is pretty much the same solution as mine, I was trying to remove the duplication.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you have to use *dynamic queries*.

Take a look [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160).

Comment: Should note that dynamic queries have their own problems. This is particularly true is you don't completely control the string (e.g. SQL Injection).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
CASE WHEN @order_by = @order_by  THEN @order_by END
```

Then there is no reason to have multiple cases.