# Syntax error near "Order By" - 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have been staring at this for too long and I can't seem to see where I went wrong.

I have a stored procedure that has to return a bunch of data where the "ExtractedText" matches the word the person is searching for:

```
Select @Command = 'select DISTINCT CaseFileEvents.InvestigatorID,convert(nvarchar,EventDate,111) as ''EventDate'',EventTime,EventDesc,TaskID,Privileged,Private,Email,HasAttachments,FName,LName, FName + '' '' + LName as Name ,CaseFileEvents.FileID,CaseFiles.FileName,ItemEntryGradeID, EventDescPlainText
                from CaseFileEvents
                join ......

                WHERE '+ @FilterField +' LIKE ''%' + @FilterQuery + '%'' ORDER BY ' + @SortName + ' ' + @SortOrder + ''; this area seems to bug out
```

@FilterField is a column in one of the tables, @FilterQuery is the word the user typed in that it is looking for. @SortName, is the name by wich it gets sorted.

Command examples: @FilterField = "ExtractedText", @FilterQuery="something", @SortName="EventID", @SortOrder="desc"

This is the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Full command:

```
WHERE ExtractedText LIKE '%add%' ORDER BY EventID desc;
```

Comment: Warning! Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: What are the values for `@FilterField`, `@FilterQuery`, `@SortName`, and `@SortOrder` when the error happens?

Comment: You are concatenating strings. Unless the parameters passed in are fully in your control, there is a chance that someone could pass in malicious content.

Comment: Consider this - what would happen if any of those variables contained a single `'`?

Comment: So please post the full command after the variables have been substituted. `@FilterQuery` may be breaking it

Comment: You should print out CMD so we can see what is being produced.  It is possible, for instance, the @FilterQuery has a single quote in it.

Comment: Print out the fully-formed query string.

Comment: The thing is it was all working before until I added the "DISTINCT". So I had to move the ORDER BY in the if statement

Comment: added the full command if the variables were entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work is because I was missing 
`WHERE EventID = convert(nvarcahr,@EventID)`
and just took out "DISTINCT"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot order by variable. You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     My_Table
WHERE
     Whatever = @something
ORDER BY
     CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'ASC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN surname
                    WHEN 'forename' THEN forename
                    WHEN 'fullname' THEN fullname
                    ELSE surname
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END ASC,
     CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'DESC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN surname
                    WHEN 'forename' THEN forename
                    WHEN 'fullname' THEN fullname
                    ELSE surname
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END DESC
```

Look in this post:

*[Can I store SQL Server sort order in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709775/can-i-store-sql-server-sort-order-in-a-variable)*