# Prevent SQL Injection in ORDER BY clause

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, sql-injection

In our DB access layer we have some dynamic query creation. For instance, we have the following method for building a part of an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
protected string BuildSortString(string sortColumn, string sortDirection, string defaultColumn)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
    {
        return defaultColumn;
    }

    return String.Format("{0} {1}", sortColumn, sortDirection);
}
```

The problem is, `sortColumn` and `sortDirection` both come from outside as strings, so of course something should be done to prevent possible injection attacks. Does anybody have any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you ***have*** to deal in strings, then white-listing is your best bet. Firstly, `sortDirection` should be pretty trivial to white-list: a case-insensitive compare to `"asc"`  / `"desc"` and you should be set. For the others, my preference would be to white-list to **known columns**, perhaps by passing in the expected `Type` for the data and validating. But at an absolute pinch, you could restrict with regex to (say) enforce they are all **strictly** alpha-numeric (in the a-z, A-Z, 0-9 range - maybe underscore if needed) - and then add `[]`, i.e.

```
return string.Format("[{0}] {1}", sortColumn, sortDirection);
```

But: strict white-list of known columns would be much better, as would an enum for the direction.

Comment: +1, I'll add a personal emphasis on "in an absolute pinch", you normally want to whitelist so you have control over which fields can be ordered by (or queried for that matter). Leaving it to the client to decide means you'll have to analyse possibly multiple clients to find out what queries to optimise. Been there, done that, no fun :-/

Comment: For the first glance it is possible to create a white-list in our case. We will give it a try, thanks Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you can change your method to accept `int` instead of `string` parameters.

```
protected string BuildSortString(int sortColumn, int sortDirection, string defaultColumn)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
    {
        return defaultColumn;
    }
//sortdirection 0-> "ASC" else "DESC"
//sorColumn 1 for your firstcolumn, 2 for your second column etc.
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", sortColumn, sortDirection==0? " ASC " : " DESC ");
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a large CASE statement where you switch based off the passed column name and direction. [There's an SO answer on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709775/can-i-store-sql-server-sort-order-in-a-variable). You're going to be looking at code like:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     My_Table
WHERE
     Whatever = @something
ORDER BY
     CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'ASC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN surname
                    WHEN 'forename' THEN forename
                    WHEN 'fullname' THEN fullname
                    ELSE surname
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END ASC,
     CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'DESC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN surname
                    WHEN 'forename' THEN forename
                    WHEN 'fullname' THEN fullname
                    ELSE surname
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END DESC
```

Comment: That type of TSQL construction tends (in my experience) to result in absolutely horrible plans that simply don't perform.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: cmd.Parameters or [EscapedString](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma), but I prefer cmd.Parameters (always work and you enjoy the Exceptions expected)

example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM userdetails WHERE USER_ID IN (?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID1", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID2", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email2;
```

> Using prepared statements with parameters helps to defend against SQL
>   injection in most common cases, when you would otherwise interpolate
>   untrusted content into a string and then execute the string as an SQL
>   statement.
>
> But a query parameter takes the place of a single value. You can't use
>   a query parameter as a substitute for a dynamic table name, column
>   name, list of values (e.g. for an IN() predicate), expressions, or SQL
>   keywords.
>
> For those cases, you can use techniques like filtering or whitelisting
>   so you don't interpolate untrusted content into your SQL strings.
>
> Filtering is where you strip out any characters that would cause
>   trouble. If you know your dynamic column name should only be
>   alphanumeric characters, then apply a filter to your variable before
>   using it in SQL. Or else just reject a variable if it doesn't match a
>   regular expression like /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/

Comment: @Destrictor Downvote is not mine, but the answer not about OP. Read title of OP again "Prevent SQL Injection in **ORDER BY clause**"

Comment: parameters do not apply for `order by` - that *cannot* be parameterised, unless you make an over-complex query like Wolfwyrd's answer

Comment: @Destrictor no, they cannot - at least, not in the same way. `order by @foo` is basically the same as saying `order by 1` - it is constant and doesn't do any sorting. As such, it is explicitly a syntax error: `The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.`

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for explaining. Still people downvoting should explain why they did such, preferably as clearly as you've done now :).

Comment: Sorry the mistake. I attemp to SQL Injection only.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public string BuildSortString(string sortColumn, SortDirection direction, string defaultColumn)
{
    string sortDirection = direction.ToString();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
    {
        return VerifyColumn(defaultColumn);
    }

    return String.Format("{0} {1}", VerifyColumn(sortColumn), sortDirection);
}

private string VerifyColumn(string column)
{
    switch (column) // fill this with a whitelist of accepted columns
    {
        case "some_column":
            return column;
    }

    return String.Empty; // the column must be invalid (do whatever you want here)
}

public enum SortDirection
{
    ASC, DESC
}
```