# Row order error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I write this query:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `control de proyectos` ORDER BY ".$_GET['ordenar']." ASC";
```

The following error appears:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ASC' at line 1

Does anyone know why?

EDIT I have to say that I have made some buttons that order teh rows like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Ordenar por Numero de proyecto"       onclick="location.href='VistaControl(Pgmaestra).php?ordenar=Numero de proyecto';"/>
```

Comment: Your `$_GET['ordenar']` is empty?

Comment: debug `$_GET['ordenar']` and check what is in it?

Comment: Also, putting `$_GET` directly into a query is a **BAD** idea

Comment: That error message is MySQL telling you stop writing vulnerable code to SQL injection.

Comment: What is the name of the column by which you are trying to ORDER? Is your table name really `control de proyectos` (containing spaces)? It's uncommon to use that sort of table and column name precisely because it's a pain in the neck to write correct queries.

Comment: The names of the columns are: Numero de proyecto, Cliente, Proveedor and Fecha

Yes, the name of the tabla is "control de proyectos" and I know it's uncommon but it's my first project and I have all the php's with that and it would be a mess to change it. In the next rpoject I will start doing it well. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have long table and column names, such as `control de projectos` and `Numero de proyecto`. While such names will function correctly in MySQL, many people believe they are difficult to use in writing queries. Your experience here confirms that belief.

The query you want is (I believe):

```
SELECT * FROM `control de proyectos` ORDER BY `Numero de proyecto` ASC
```

Notice the backticks surrounding the long table and column names. Your php code doesn't generate the backticks correctly. What you need is something like this.

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `control de proyectos` 
                      ORDER BY `" . $_GET['ordenar'] . "`  ASC";
```

That will put the backticks in the right place to make your query work.

Now look: in comments people have said it's dangerous to use the result of a `$_GET[]` operation directly to create a query. That is very true. Crackers -- so-called script-kiddies -- have all kinds of cheap website cracking scripts that look for these kinds of vulnerabilities. They don't even need skill to do it. If you use this kind of code some script kiddie **will attack and destroy** your web site.

Please look up how to avoid SQL injection in `ORDER BY` clauses. For example: [Prevent SQL Injection in ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317341/prevent-sql-injection-in-order-by-clause)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think that part of the query that you have posted: `" . $_GET['ordenar']" . ` is wrong and should be changed by: `" . $_GET['ordenar']." `
I did it and now it appears this message: Unknown column '' in 'order clause'. You know why?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my typographic error. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ordenar =$_GET['ordenar'];

if(isset($ordenar))
 {
   $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `control de proyectos` 
                         ORDER BY '".$ordenar."'  ASC";

}
```

Comment: With this, it appears an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'proyectos ORDER BY 'Fecha de entrega al cliente' ASC' at line 1

Comment: I have to say that I have made some buttons that order teh rows like this: <input type="button" value="Ordenar por Numero de proyecto" onclick="location.href='VistaControl(Pgmaestra).php?ordenar=Numero de proyecto';"/>